# PSExec and Powershell fails to run a program located in Program Files (x86)

Tags: powershell, escaping, quoting

I am struggling to use Psexec inside of a PS script to execute an interactive program.
I have tried this:

```
PsExec.exe -i \\192.168.100.95 -u Administrador -p Test1234 cmd /c "echo . | powershell notepad" 2> $null
```

... and it runs perfectly fine. Notepad is launched on a remote machine. Now, when I want to run .exe from Program Files (x86) I get absolutely nothing.
I have tried this variations to run 1.exe located in ProgramFiles(x86):

```
PsExec.exe -i \\192.168.100.95 -u Administrador -p Test1234 cmd /c "echo . | powershell "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\1.exe"" 2> $null

PsExec.exe -i \\192.168.100.95 -u Administrador -p Test1234 cmd /c "echo . | powershell "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}" + "\1.exe"" 2> $null
```

However none of them work. Any idea what´s wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
psexec cmd /c 'echo . | powershell "& \"${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\1.exe\"' 2>$null
```

<sup>Note: To better focus on the fundamentals of the solution, I've simplified the `psexec` command, but the original command should work too.</sup>

- The entire string passed to `cmd /k` is *single*-quoted to prevent PS from interpolating elements up front, notably `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` whose expansion should be deferred until the command is executed on the *target* machine.

  - Note that you normally need a *double-quoted* string when you pass a command line to `cmd /c` *when invoking from `cmd.exe` itself*. From within PowerShell, however, this is *not* a requirement: PowerShell first parses the string - whether single- or double-quoted originally - interpolates, if applicable, and then passes the *resulting* string *double-quoted* to the external command.
- Note the `& \"...\"` construct in the context of the `powershell` argument, which ensures that the path with embedded spaces is correctly executed.

  - Curiously, PS requires `"` chars. to be escaped as `\"` when a parameter is passed *from the outside world* (as opposed to escaping as `` `" `` inside the realm of PS).
  - The command passed to `powershell` as a whole *must* be *double-quoted*, because `cmd.exe` - in whose context `powershell` is invoked due to `cmd /c` - only recognizes double quotes as parameter delimiters and only double quotes protect the enclosed content (mostly) from interpretation.

---

**Why your commands didn't work:**

- The primary problem was that the executable path that you wanted  `powershell.exe` to invoke ended up containing *spaces* (`C:\Program Files...`), causing PowerShell not to recognize the entire path as a single argument. Such a path must be (a) *quoted* and (b) invoked with `&`, the call operator.
  (In the 2nd attempt, with `+ ...` (string concatenation), you would have had to use `&` also, and enclose the concatenation in `(...)`).

  - For debugging, using `cmd /k` instead of `cmd /c` can give you a better sense of how the command is ultimately executed (`/k` keeps the console window open after execution of the command).
- A subtler point is that by using a *double-quoted* string overall, `${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}` was expanded on the *source* machine rather than on the *target* machine, where the definition of that environment variable may or may not be the same.

Comment: This is simply awesome. Great break down of how it should be done. Thank you @mklement0. I had to remove the space between ProgramFiles and (x86) to make it work but other than that your comment is flawless.

Comment: @Okrx: My pleasure; glad to hear it. Re extraneous space: serves me right for faking the variable on my 32-bit machine... Thanks for the feedback; I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You're putting yourself in Escape Hell by mixing PowerShell, CMD and `PsExec`. If all you want is run an executable on a remote host, just stick with CMD and PsExec (run the command from CMD too):

```
PsExec.exe -i \\192.168.100.95 -u Administrador -p Test1234 cmd /c echo. ^| "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\1.exe" 2>nul
```

That way you just need to escape the pipe (`^|`) and put the path with spaces in double quotes.

Comment: While that certainly simplifies the invocation, note how the OP mentions  "struggling to use Psexec _inside of a PS script_" (emphasis mine).

Comment: This command works perfectly fine and I'm really grateful for your help but this needs to be run from a PS script.